# SimpleInjector as default DI in Sitecore 8.2

Tags: dependency-injection

I read this post today about replacing Sitecores 8.2 default DI (https://medium.com/@structuredcode/replacing-the-default-di-container-in-sitecore-8-2-4e65d4956c99), but the example is for Autofac. We use SimpleInjector, but I'm sure not how to do this for SimpleInjector; does anyone have any examples?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem with the simple injector container is that they do not provide a conforming container option. [They don't like it](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/41). So to replace it with Simple Injector requires a bit more effort.

In this post [Habitat DI with Simple Injector](http://www.sitecorenutsbolts.net/2016/09/17/Habitat-Dependency-Injection-with-Sitecore-8-2/) - I explained how to use SI in a conforming way to register your dependencies for Habitat projects.

You could take a similar approach with replacing the default Sitecore container. Using the custom `ServiceProviderBuilder` from the post in the question you could do this:

```cs
public class SimpleInjectorServiceProviderBuilder
  : BaseServiceProviderBuilder
{
    protected override IServiceProvider BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        var container= new Container();

        // Register Sitecore services in SI
        var containerCache = new List<Type>();
        foreach (var serviceDescriptor in dependencyInjectionArgs.ServiceCollection)
        {
            // Safety check so we don't try to register the same type twice
            if (containerCache.Contains(serviceDescriptor.ServiceType))
            {
              continue;
            }
            Lifestyle siScope;
            switch (serviceDescriptor.Lifetime)
            {
              case ServiceLifetime.Singleton:
                siScope = Lifestyle.Singleton;
                break;
              case ServiceLifetime.Transient:
                siScope = Lifestyle.Transient;
                break;
              case ServiceLifetime.Scoped:
              default:
                siScope = Lifestyle.Scoped;
                break;
            }
            container.Register(serviceDescriptor.ServiceType, serviceDescriptor.ImplementationType, siScope);
            containerCache.Add(serviceDescriptor.ServiceType);
        }

        // Return service provider adaptor.
        return container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
    }
}
```

As you can see - instead of calling the `.Populate` method and passing the service collection in, you have to enumerate through the service collection and more manually register your services. (Please note, this is PoC and untested code :) )

Comment: Nice, thanks Richard. I'll take a look at this. We're using WebActivatorEx to wire up DI at the moment in 8.1 update 2 so my plan is to upgrade and move to using the out of the box DI hooks.